# How could Sirius buy a broomstick for Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, sirius-black, gringotts

I don’t understand how Sirius managed to buy Harry a firebolt when he was a widely known mass murderer. I recall them mentioning that they took the gold from Sirius’ vault and had it shipped to him. However, how do you buy something with just your vault number? I just don’t buy the Goblins would be so lax on security.  Also you’d think someone would have alerted the Ministry if a mass murderer who broke out of Azkaban is making accessing his vault.

Is there something in the book I’m missing?

Comment: I closed your question [as a duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) of the linked question since it seems to be covered there. If it's not, feel free to [edit] your question to explain how it isn't.

Comment: Thank you, I did a search before posting, but it looks like I’m not good at searching. Yes, this answers my question.

Comment: Owl Order??? Maybe he used an owl order under a fake name...

Comment: "Did the check clear?" "Yes." "Ship it!"